# How to fix delay in launching and blank white screen in Android application

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

I am developing an android app which displays a white screen on startup for long time while launching it for the first time and after that it is working fine.How to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: put your heavy loading task in different thread or use AsyncTask to do that.

Comment: even i face this problem sometimes. It is highly seen in devices with MarshMallow.

Comment: Are you using android studio 2.0 above version?

Comment: There is no way to fix it. That's how `ART` virtual machine is working. It prepares somehow the the APK right after it has been installed to speed up it's further launches.

Comment: I am using Android studio 2.2

Comment: disable InstantRun in android studio

Answer (score 0):

First,remove unused Activity,Service,Receiver from your manifest file.
Then, using other thread for some heavy task at Application's onCreate()
Last, using an welcome page as the window's background at your launcher Activity

Answer (score -2):

We can change the background color of of Blank screen.
Use styles

```
    <resources>
<style name="Theme" parent="android:style/Theme" />
<style name="Theme.MainTheme" parent="Theme">
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_drawable</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Then in manifest file

```
    <application
android:name="@string/app_name"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/Theme.MainTheme"
 >
```